# Unseen Quotation marks are showing up on my Text file

Tags: excel

> Column in question is Full Name, in excel (.xls), the name is displayed as John Smith, even when selecting the cell, in the f(x) text box it shoes as John Smith (no special chars are visible)

Attempted to fix by :
1) Ctrl + F to search for special chars "
2) Clicked on Data and Text to Columns to see if any special chars are shown and nothing is seen

> Excel says there are no " chars
>
> save file as .txt however all my names are wrapped in quotation marks like "John, Smith"

Comment: Do all your data values with the extra double-quotes contain a comma ??

Comment: yes, they do, they look like this John, Smith

Comment: Yeah, removing them helped, do you know why that is the case that it wraps the cell or data with the tick marks?

Comment: I know that when Excel makes a .cs:v file, it adds the double quotes .

Comment: I think that is by design when the field (cell) contains a comma. And most programs that read text/csv files should be able to deal with it. One way to avoid it is to save as formatted text (space-separated), or create your own VBA routine.

Comment: I see, anyways, thank you so much for taking the time to assist me with this. You saved me some time.